# CDN links are not working(in the app.blade.php) in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, cdn

> app.blade.php

This is my app.blade.php file CDN links in this file are not working in the data.balde.php file i have used these links for the datetimepicker which is in the date.blade.php file.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
    <!-- Styles for datepicker-->

     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

        <link href="//cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/e8bddc60e73c1ec2475f827be36e1957af72e2ea/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">


            <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

            <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>

            <script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/e8bddc60e73c1ec2475f827be36e1957af72e2ea/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script> 

    </head>
</body>
</html>
```

> date.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')

   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
            });
        </script>
    </div>
     </div>
@endsection
```

Here is the console error

[image]

Comment: Check your network tab if they loaded properly.

Comment: yes it is loading properly

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your body tag

```
 <div class="container">
    @yield('content')
 </div>
```

Put the id on input.

```
<div class='input-group date' >
    <input type='text' id='datetimepicker1' class="form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
   </span>
</div>
```